# LaTeX -> dvi/pdf/ps -> list of (x, y, font_name, character_id)

Tags: latex

Input: I have a LaTeX file, with plain text & math formulas.

Desired output: I want a list of elements, where each element is:

x-coordinate
y-coordinate
font_name
character_id

Basically, I want to take a LaTeX file, r"render it", but instead of printing it / getting an image, I want it to say "okay, you have a Sigma symbol here, then you have a 'x' symbol there, ...)

What's the easiest way to achieve this? (I'm on Linux)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also [dvitype](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/dvitype.html).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks!